# How do I resolve a conflict between my Anaconda environment and Opencv cv2?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to run a Python script in my terminal that uses the cv2 library and I am getting the following error message.  It appears that there is a conflict between two instances of `RunLoopModeTracker` in my Anaconda environment.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda and the same thing happens.

> objc[80110]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both
> /Users/satyadoraisamy/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtCore
> (0x1079527f0) and
> /Users/satyadoraisamy/opt/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.9.7.dylib
> (0x11b86ba80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process.
> Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries.
> Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries
> are being loaded.

Any idea how to solve this (or specify which of the two instances I want to use)?

Thanks.